# C# - Convert UTF8 String into bits, modify bits, and convert back into UTF8 String

Tags: c#, utf-8, encode

For a project I'm working on, I need to be able to convert a UTF8 string into bits or bytes for modification and back.
(Bit/Byte type doesn't matter.. '138' or '00000001' or '0A' - as long as I'm able to modify it as a string and convert the Bytes back into a string)

I've tried a few things, but nothing has worked.
For the most part, I've been trying to take the result of `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` and convert the bytes into a modifiable string and back, but haven't had any success. Also tried doing the same using a test string into a `BitArray` with no better luck.

Here's what I'm trying to do in a better example (pseudocode)

```cs
string input = "ABC";

Byte[] bytes = StringToBytes(input);
Byte[] bytes2;

string bytestring;
foreach (Byte byte in bytes) {
    bytestring = byte.ToString();
    /// modify bytestring to the value of a different byte here ///
    bytes2.Add(bytestring.ToByte());
}

return BytesToString(bytes2);
```

Return: `'ACD'` (or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to read a file into a byte[] array, modify those bytes, and convert that back to a string, you could do something like this:

```
// read the file into a byte array
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFileName);

// modify the bytes

// now convert back to a UTF string
var stringFromByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I modify each byte as a string? For example.. if bytes[1] is '438' how can I read that as a string, turn it into say.. '111' and save it again as a byte?

Comment: Ahm, a byte value is 0 to 255. It is a `byte` data type. How can it be '438'?

Comment: I honestly just typed a random number for the example

Comment: If you're trying to modify the byte[] value, just use `bytes[0] = (byte)128;`. That would convert decimal 128 to a byte and assign it to the first byte in the bytes array.